# How to find all overloaded functions

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I'm porting a complex code base from 32 to 64 bits.

During the planning, one of the possible issues which was underlined was wrong overload resolution.

To illustrate:

```
#include <cstddef>

int f(unsigned int a) { return 0; }

int f(unsigned long long a) { return 1; }

size_t x;

int main() {
    return f(x);
}
```

would generate no warnings; and yet return 0 under a 32 bit system, but 1 under a 64 bit system.

Is there a standard tool to find all such cases?

I'm using both Windows and Linux, so platform-specific tools are not excluded either way!

Comment: You can use nm on linux and dumpbin on windows to list all the functions in your tool / library and then make a list of overloaded ones.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile as is. In both cases (32bit and 64bit) the result would result in an implicit conversion which again is ambigious in your case. https://godbolt.org/g/1HtAKZ

Comment: Possibly you can rescue the example code by using `ptrdiff_t` (signed) instead of `size_t`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Unfortunately not: https://godbolt.org/g/tt0F62

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Oh, it does compile nicely on some system with `ptrdiff_t`, which would be the point. E.g. it compiles in Windows. :) Note that when you use `<cstddef>` you have to use `std::ptrdiff_t` for portability. I generally recommend `<stddef.h>` for this reason, and others. But will people listen? Nah. Hrmf. </rant>

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Both variants don't work on godbolt. May I suggest to use this for the example: https://godbolt.org/g/WMYqHA

Comment: Uhm, I'm not the OP. I really liked the way Godbolt placed the diagnostics in context in the source. Is there some extension doing that for Visual Studio?

Comment: I get `error: call of overloaded 'f(size_t&)` is ambiguous`

Comment: Any tool which list all functions should allow to find duplicated name, you can then check argument type.

Comment: Amended the example, of course I was thinking of unsigned values. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: And... well, the fact thait it doesn't work in Godbolt IS the solution! Visual Studio does not give warnings -but gcc does. I only have to compile under Linux; if it works, there are no worries.